# Leak in 3/8 refrigerant line and replacement

Tags: hvac, leak

After a great deal of troubleshooting, we found a leak in the 3/8 inch line.  The whole line set in runs from upstairs into a crawl space then under the ground to the outside unit. Can we just replace the 3/8 line or would we need to replace the whole line set? I only want to replace about a 20ft section from the crawl space to the outside unit.  Maybe we just replace both lines for peace of mind.

Comment: Do you know *where* on the line the leak is?

Comment: You'll probably want to hire this one out. It'll illegal to intentionally release the refrigerant (any of them) into the atmosphere, and you have to have a license to buy the refrigerant to refill it. IMHO, may as well hire a pro and get a warranty on the repair work while you're at it instead of trusting your own soldering skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you (or at least someone qualified to work on refrigeration systems in your jurisdiction) can replace just a small section of the lineset to fix a leak. There is no need to touch the other line when fixing the one.

However each joint has a higher chance of leaks than a continuous run. So it's better that repairs happen in places that are accessible after the walls are patched up.

Also it pays to investigate *why* a leak happened there and mitigate the chance of a new leak. There is no point to replace a line when it's going to rub out on a nail again in a few months.

Comment: I had a professional come out to take care of this.  We only had to replace the 3/8 line.  He put a pressure test on it and heard it leaking inside of a conduit.  This conduit had 45 degree pipe fittings in several locations.  We suspect the 3/8 pipe was kinked at a point underground in the crawl space.  He installed the line and did a pressure test overnight.  The unit is working great now.  i suspect this leak caused the older unit to go bad.  I replaced the old unit about 3 years ago.  I was having various problems with the new unit and this leak might have been the issue.  Thanks to all.